# Softlayer API - Listing Evault Backup Statuses

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is there a way to pull the evault backup info through an API call? Was looking into a way of producing a report with successful/failed backup jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this RestFul request:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getEvaultNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask(SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)[virtualGuest,hardware,backupJobDetails]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I was able to pull all info i was looking for with URL suggested.

Did a little bit of digging into the Object Mask and services, and the string looks pretty clear! And good find with using a custom type with object mask (SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6) since the getEvaultNetworkStorage doesn't return the backupJobDetails property.

Comment: The only question I had though is why can't we just directly request SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6 service and then set the object mask from there?

Like I tried doing https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/Softlayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6
Couldn't get it to work. Is it because all the requests should go through Softlayer_Account? 
Please, advise

Comment: Think I understood now, the Softla‌​yer_Network_Storage_‌​Backup_Evault_Versio‌​n6 service simply doesn't have getObject() method and therefore requires the initialization parameter first